# How do i use border layouts?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on Layouts in  Java. I'm trying to combine different layouts. So i have created a login Screen using Spring Layout, GridLayout and Border Layout. 
The MainFrame (JFrame) uses GridLayout. The GridLayout consists of 2 Panel (North Panel and Main Panel). The Main Panel consists of the Jlabel, JTextfield and JButton of which I have no problem of. My problem is in the North Panel which uses Border Layout. It contains a JLabel (lblWelcome). I have been trying to bring the label to the center of the panel using Border Layout but it still aligns to the left. This is the below code:

```
  JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome To The Login Screen");
  JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  northPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
  northPanel.add(lblWelcome, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Login Screen :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `JLabel` is actually correctly centered, but its text isn't.

Simply change its creation to :

```
JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("Welcome To The Login Screen", SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Comment: But I really didn't see any difference in  my code above when I changed it to Border Layout.LINE_START.   I had the same result when I used Border Layout.LINE_START and Border Layout.CENTER. Any Idea why?

Comment: It may be normal behaviour, since you add only one component to it, it takes the whole space.